# Android Tokyo itinerary app that detects what train I am riding right now

Tags: android, gps, itinerary

I often board a train and then open Google Maps to refine the itinerary (get off at station A and at 12:05 take the Express B to station C then change... whatever is the best to reach my destination faster, depending on what express/local trains happen to be around at that precise time).

**PROBLEM**: Google Maps does not understand that I am already riding the train. It thinks I am walking nearby the track, and tells me to first walk to the nearest train station. This results in a time shift: Google Maps calculates the best itinerary from station A at 12:10 even though I have already passed it a few minutes ago. This is very important because a few minutes make the difference between missing or taking an Express.

So, I am looking for an app that would understand which train I am riding right now.

To understand whether I am in a train or in a car on a closely parallel road, it could use my travel position/speed (GPS), acceleration/deceleration smoothness (motion sensors), or recognize the Wi-Fi networks within the train or at stations. Or just ask me whether I am in the train, and then use the GPS and trains data to find out which one.

Requirements:

- < 5000 JPY ($50)
- Android
- Works in Tokyo at least